# Is there official terminology for anime series that run less than the standard length?

Tags: anime-production, terminology

I'm referring to the shorter-in-duration anime, such as *Aiura*, *Recorder and Randsell*, and *Morita-san is Quiet*.  These anime do not run for the "normal" duration of 22 or more minutes.

Is there any official terminology for these types of anime?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but according to Japanese Wikipedia articles for those series, they can be called **tanpen anime** (短編アニメ, short anime).

[Aiura](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%82%E3%81%84%E3%81%86%E3%82%89#.E3.83.86.E3.83.AC.E3.83.93.E3.82.A2.E3.83.8B.E3.83.A1):

> 2013年4月から6月までテレビ東京・ニコニコ動画にて、5分枠の**短編アニメ**で放送された。
>   From April to June 2013, a 5 minute **tanpen anime** was aired on TV Tokyo and Nico Nico Douga.

[Recorder and Randsell](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%AA%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%80%E3%83%BC%E3%81%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%B3%E3%83%89%E3%82%BB%E3%83%AB#.E3.83.86.E3.83.AC.E3.83.93.E3.82.A2.E3.83.8B.E3.83.A1):

> 5分枠の**短編アニメ**で、2012年1月より『リコーダーとランドセル ド♪』のタイトルでテレビ埼玉、KBS京都にて放送された。
>   A 5 minute **tanpen anime** was aired starting in January 2012 on TV Saitama and KBS Kyoto as "Recorder and Randsell Do♪".

[Morita-san](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%A3%AE%E7%94%B0%E3%81%95%E3%82%93%E3%81%AF%E7%84%A1%E5%8F%A3#.E3.83.86.E3.83.AC.E3.83.93.E3.82.A2.E3.83.8B.E3.83.A1):

> 『森田さんは無口。』のタイトルで、2011年7月から9月までテレビ埼玉、KBS京都、ニコニコチャンネルにて放送された5分枠の**短編アニメ**。
>   From July to September 2011, TV Saitama, KBS Kyoto, and Nico Nico channel aired a 5 minute **tanpen anime** with the title as "Morita-san wa Mukuchi.".